# One variable that could be an instance of two classes that each have different methods

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a base class `BatchLogic`. This class has two other classes that extend it, `ClassBatchLogic` and `DataBatchLogic`. The base class has some methods that must be available on both children classes, however `ClassBatchLogic` and `DataBatchLogic` each have methods that aren't present in the other counterpart. For example, I could call `ClassBatchLogic.initVerticalSplitters()` but can't call `DataBatchLogic.initVerticalSplitters()` because the method isn't present there (and vice versa). I am confident the two children classes will never be included in the same HTML page at the same time.

My problem comes when I try to create instance members of those children classes. If I create a single variable `let batchLogic: ClassBatchLogic | DataBatchLogic;` and then instantiate it in the two pages I have a TS error when I try to access a method of `DataBatchLogic` somewhere in other TypeScript files due to the possibility of the variable being an instance of `ClassBatchLogic` and not having those methods. The error is `TS2339: Property does not exist on type 'DataBatchLogic | ClassBatchLogic'. Property does not exist on type 'ClassBatchLogic'`.

On the other hand, If I have two variables that each represent an instance of each class, I run into a problem where I can't access a common method (existing in the `BatchLogic` parent class) from a TypeScript file that is included in both HTML pages because either of the variables could be present.

How would one go about creating an elegant solution to this? I could always check which variable is present manually, but I'm looking for the best suited OOP-oriented solution to the problem.

Comment: Type guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: This is useful on a function scope, however if I go with the single variable route I would be looking for something that would work on the entire file, since there will potentially be dozens of calls to the instantiated variable and it would be a lot of duplicated code if I have to check every time if it's an instance of one of the classes